# fedora 35 : file with drive extension

Tags: filesystems, fedora

I have a file with "drive" as extension in nemo workplace tab : I don't knoww what it is.
It's got a random name at each boot like : o_____o_O_o______.drive" and I cannot do anything with : no stat, no ls, nothing ?

Does anyone know what it is ?

Comment: Are you remotely mounting any filesystems, e.g., Google Drive?

Comment: nothing of that sort, the only peculiar thing on that server is Jellyfin. The rest is nothing but standard fedora server with lightdm.

Comment: I don't use `nemo` but I'm wondering if you run it in debug mode if some useful messages might appear.  Doing something like quitting `nemo` (`$ nemo -q` ?) and then `$ NEMO_DEBUG=all nemo --debug`.

Comment: I put it there for you to see but tries to manipulate didn't raise any log event : https://pastebin.com/nQ0nGB8q

Comment: I don't see anything relevant in the log either.  I was hoping more verbosity that would show the origin of your `.drive` file.  If you use a different file manger, e.g., Thunar, does the mystery file appear there?  Perhaps a question at [`nemo`'s issue tracker](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues) could help explain your mystery file.

Comment: actually I just went on fedora 36 : it now disappeared ?? I guess Ill never know. O_O thanks anyway ;)